# what is a parameter and hyperprameter

Tags: machine-learning

I hear in many articles the word parameters and hyperparameters but I don't know what they mean by that.
Are they variable or the weights of the nodes?

explain me in an intuitive way as an analogy please

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.